# Residual error when setting measurement matrix in compresssive sensing

Tags: image-processing, matlab, estimation, compressive-sensing

I have an issue when implementing compressive sensing to recover sparse vector. Assume I have sparse vector $x$ of length, for example, $(256,1)$. $x = [x_1,x_2,.....x_{256}]$. This vector is transformed into time domain using Fourier matrix, $X = iFFT(x)$, and then convoluted with a channel $h$ resulting $y = X*h$, where * denotes the convolution operation. Let's make $H$ denote the toeplitz matrix of vector $h$ correspondent to $y = XH$

$case-1: $ Let's describe the above process as below:

$1). $ $X = F'x$ , where $F$ is Fourier matrix transformation obtained in matlab by `F = dftmtx(256)`. and then $F'$ is the inverse Fourier matrix. This $X$ is correspondent to `X = ifft(x)`.

$2).$ The signal $y = HX$ can be expressed in function of $x$ as $y = HF'x$. The use of compressive sensing here is straightforward by putting $y = Ax$ where $A= HF'$ is the measurement matrix. Therefore, sparse vector $x$ can be recovered using any algorithm such as OMP, MP or any other.

$case-2: $ Assume that we transformed the vector $x$ into time domain using $iFFT$ operation, but his time in vector of $32$. It means that we take every $32$ elements of $x$ and then perform $iFFT$ for it. This process can be performed in matlab as, `X1 = reshape(x,32,[]); X_2 = reshape(ifft(x),[],1);` This $X_2$ is equivalent into the $X$ mentioned in case_1  but with Fourier transformation of vector $32$

$1)$ Similarly to above manipulation, $X_2 = F'_{32} x$, where $F'_{32}$ can be expressed as below :

[image]

where $X_2$ here is correspondent into $X$ in the case_1, and $F'_{32}$ is inverse Fourier matrix of size $32$ obtained in matlab as `dftmtx(32)'` .

$2)$ The signal $y$ can be expressed similarly to case_1 as $y = HX_2 = HF'_{32} x$. BUT, performing compressive sensing into this case, $y = A_2x$  where $A_2 =  HF'_{32}$ doesn't recover the vector $x$.

My question, theoretically, any compressive sensing algorithm such as OMP, MP should be able to recover $x$ in both case since measurement matrices are known and then should be straightforward, but in case $2$ where measurement matrix $A_2$, the CS doesn't work? A small residual error happens when performing that in matlab, so is there mathematical expression for that error? Is it possible to overcome that issue ?

EDIT: 
Here is the method how to create the $A_1$ and $A_2$ in matlab

```
F = dftmtx(256)/256;     %%Fourier matrix 
X = F*x;                 %%x is sparse vector of length(256,1) and X time domain of x
h = randn(32,1);         %%channel 
H = toeplitz([h(1) zeros(1,255) ], [h.' zeros(1,255) ]).'  %%toeplitx matrix
y = H*X;                 %%recieved signale 

A1 = H*F;               %measurement matrix 
x_hat = omp(A1,y,q)    %estimated x, and q is the number of sparse 

%%% creating A2 
F2 = kron(eye(8), dftmtx(32)/32);   %Fourier matrix 
X2 = F2*x;                % ifft of reshaped x 
y2 = H*X2; 


A2 = H*F2; 
x_hat = omp(A2,y2,q)    %estimated x, and q is the number of sparse
```

where omp is copressive sensing OMP algorithm. In case of building the measurement matrix using $A_1$, x_hat can be recovered well but when using the $A_2$, a small error occurs, it means that estimated signal can't be demodulated and have BER = 0 compared with original x

Here you can get the complete code [Here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ebqq932qjj1i7u8/CS_code.rar/file)
Thank you

Comment: When I put $y=X_2 = F'_{32}x$ , then put the measurement matrix $A_2 = F'_{32}$ it's ok. but when I multiply with matrix $H$, Compressive sensing can't recover vector $x$. $h$ is random vector generated in matlab by h = randn(32,1); and H = toeplitz([h(1) zeros(1,256-1) ], [h.' 256-1) ]).';  That's really strange !

Comment: I'm having a hard time to follow your explanations. Could you add a clarification how to obtain $A_1$ and $A_2$ for case 1 and 2 respectively, so that $y=A_1 x$ and $y = A_2 x$ are the two sparse recovery problems you are trying to solve for case 1 and 2? A short equation or a few lines of Matlab would work.

Comment: @Florian Could I have your email to send you the code I made. .

Comment: Sorry, but that defeats the purpose of DSP Stackexchange. Share your relevant information here so everyone else can profit from it as well. There is no need to post lengthy codes, the generation of the matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ should only be one or two lines if you do it right.

Comment: @Florian  got it. thank you ...  I added the code.  for that I was asking if CS doesn't work in that case,  we can use (Sparse signal recovery) SSR since the matrix $A_1 = H*F$ and $A_2 = H*F2$ are square in that case.

Comment: I see that in the last line of the code one of your arguments for omp is y instead of y2.

Comment: @DSPNovice  sorry for that error,  I modified it, it's y2, it's not y.

Comment: That helps, but we're not quite there yet: Your code does not work: F2 is 256x256 so you cannot multiply F2 with `reshape(x,32,8)`, which is 32x8. Also, you haven't indicated the value of `q` you are using (or how to generate `x` really). If you ditch the reshape, it seems both versions work for me for the example I tested (`q=3`).

Comment: I modified it, in all cases it's x,  the q=128,   I generated the data x as modulated data using QAM modulation of length 128 and other values are 0. Then, when demodulating the data and compare with original bits, in first case, error are zeros while in second case always small error is still existed. @Florian

Comment: I see that the equation shows F2 Hermitian matrix. You can try if taking conj() of dftmtx makes a difference.

Comment: @DSPNovice I set F2 = kron(eye(8), conj(dftmtx(32)/32)); , I get the same result.

Comment: Since Hermitian is conjugate transpose, can you try conj()' instead of conj() if that makes a difference

Comment: With your code and `q=128`, both versions `A1` and `A2` give a reconstruction error that is essentially zero (i.e., 1e-15 due to rounding errors) on my computer.

Comment: @Florian  I agree, but when you do that calculation over  for example 100 times, you will notice that residual error. However using the measurement matrix F1, everything will be ok! ..  I uploaded the code into the question..

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I have zero errors for both A1, A2 in 100 trials for q ranging from 100 up to 255 (to my surprise).

Comment: @Florian could you please run the code I added and see. have you downloaded the code ?  And could you please send the omp algorithm you running

Comment: No I cannot since your link had already expired 1 hour after you posted it. I'll have to check if I'm allowed to share this code.

Comment: @Florian Sorry for that .. I don't know that linke will expire soon.  OK .. I updated the link of the code https://www.mediafire.com/file/ebqq932qjj1i7u8/CS_code.rar/file    .. it's here

Comment: @Florian Did you get the code ? .... did you get what I mean by the residual error I get ?

Comment: Yep .. that's strange !! Maybe because of losing the orthogonality in second case ! I'm not sure. In first case, when you multiply by Fourier matrix, the orthogonality will be perfect, but in second case, That's won't be orthogonal anymore ..  maybe

Comment: Share the code over Microsoft OneDrive / Google Drive / Dropbox where it doesn't have expiration time.